# I guess im confused with the structure of the html. I cant seem to set the 3 images side by side with flex-box. it needs to be with flexbox

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to have the `<section-text>` on top of the 3 images. The images should be side by side (left to right) using flexbox, but I just can't seem to do it. I'm almost 100% sure that the structure of my HTML is missing something. I tried wrapping each article in `<div>` but then the section-text would be squeezed all the way onto the left and the `<hr>` would be vertical instead of horizontal.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed:700|Roboto:100,300,700');


html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 10px;
  line-height: 3.5em;
  font-weight: 300;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5 {
  font-family: Roboto Condensed;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 9em;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 5em;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  line-height: 3em;
  color: white;
  text-shadow: #020819 8px -20px 9px
}

h3 {
  font-size: 4.2em;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 1em;
  margin-top: 0;
}

h4 {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  letter-spacing: 0.4;
  line-height: 1em;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

h5 {
  font-size: 1.2em;
  line-height: 1em;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.dark-background {
  background-color: rgb(25, 33, 41);
  color: white;
}

.service-box img {
  width: 125px;
}

#team .section-text {
  font-size: 1.9em;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

#team .member-name {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-weight: 700;
}

#team {
  padding: 75px 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

#team>div>article {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

#team p {
  width: 60%;
  margin: 10px auto;
}

#team hr {
  margin: 20px auto 30px auto;
  width: 40%;
}

.section-team img {
  width: 250px;
  height: 180px;
}
```

```html
<section id="team" class="dark-background section-team">

  <div>
    <h4 class="section-text">Team</h4>
    <p class="section-text">Our team collectively has 75 years of experience. Odds are, when you jump out of the plane with these professionals, you wont go splat.</p>
    <hr></hr>
  </div>
  <div>
    <article>
      <p class="member-name"><strong>Harold Rothsten,</strong></p>
      <img src="https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/ih-materials/uploads/upload_c18b1c463b80090894237a262dfdfbad.jpg" alt=" diving in cloudy day">
    </article>

    <article>
      <p class="member-name"><strong>Susan Phillips,</strong></p>
      <img src="https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/ih-materials/uploads/upload_a18d6123a7c8e75f7e70a4e59b941093.jpg" width=" 200px" alt=" skydiving blue sky">
    </article>

    <article>
      <p class="member-name"><strong>Tyalor Roberts,</strong></p>
      <img src="https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/ih-materials/uploads/upload_7104a331530d1b0611da55093b7dc421.jpg" width=" 200px" alt=" diving in a sunn day">
    </article>
  </div>

</section>
```

Comment: What's the issue? The text is indeed above the three images in the CodePen.

Answer (score 0):

Only the direct children of a flex container are flex items:

```css
.example-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="example-container">
  <div class="ex-item-1">
    ex-item-1
    <article>article</article>
  </div>
  <div class="ex-item-2">ex-item-2</div>
  <div class="ex-item-3">ex-item-3</div>
</div>
```

In the above example, `ex-item-1`, `ex-item-2`, and `ex-item-3` are flex-items, so the CSS would center them vertically and horizontally, but not the article because it is not a direct descendant of the flex container.

Comment: That, combined with creating a new flex container for your article, is why the elements aren't aligning properly